# Update Dart SDK from 2.10.3 to 2.12.0 in Vscode

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the following error when I try to update the environment sdk in flutter.

> The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.3.

Because my_app requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because my_app requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

`flutter doctor -v` gives me the following result

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.2.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0 at /Users/mustafazaki/flutter
    • Framework revision b22742018b (4 weeks ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
    • Engine revision a9d88a4d18
    • Dart version 2.13.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mustafazaki/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.1, Build version 12A7403
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 67F57BF6-B6BC-4061-9BFD-01D38275C4E1 • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-1 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      91.0.4472.77

• No issues found!
```

Also, why I can't see the latest dart update on vscode? It shows me only 2.10.3

[image]

`flutter clean` also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried `flutter upgrade`?

Comment: yup! tried that too

Comment: if you are using android studio change it from the plugins setting

Comment: I am using vscode

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to modify the target Dart environment of the Flutter app in its pubspec.yaml file. Update the environment section to:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"
```

It was mentioned in the Dart SDK [changelog](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#2120---2021-03-03) back in 2021. Also, if `flutter upgrade` doesn't work. Try adding `--force` in the command.